# Creating shared and static libraries using g++ (under Windows)

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, shared-libraries, static-libraries

How do I create static and dynamic libraries for Windows using g++?

I've found a few commands for Linux for creating `.so` files and I've tried to apply them on a Windows shell, but they build `.dll` files that my applications fail to link with at runtime.

I've only managed to build `.dll` files using Visual C++ but I would like to build them manually on the command line, preferably using `g++`. I would also like to know how to build static libraries too for Windows.

Comment: This ain't so trivial when you are in use with linux `-shared -fPIC` way of doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prefix with the attribute :

```
__declspec(dllexport)...
```

all the features you want to expose.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/a90k134d.aspx).

Example for a C function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Add(int a, int b)
{
  return (a + b);
}
```

This can be simplified using `MACROS`: everything is explained on this [helpful page](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/building-dlls-with-mingw/).

**For C++ classes, you only need to prefix each class (not every single method)**

I usually do it that way :

> Note : *The following also ensures portability...*

***Include File :***

```
// my_macros.h
//
// Stuffs required under Windoz to export classes properly
// from the shared library...
// USAGE :
//      - Add "-DBUILD_LIB" to the compiler options
//
#ifdef __WIN32__
#ifdef BUILD_LIB
#define LIB_CLASS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIB_CLASS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define LIB_CLASS       // Linux & other Unices : leave it blank !
#endif
```

***Usage :***

```
#include "my_macros.h"

class LIB_CLASS MyClass {
}
```

Then, to **build**, simply :

- Pass the option `-DBUILD_LIB` to the usual compiler command line
- Pass the option `-shared` to the usual linker command line

Comment: For static libraries, just pass `-static` instead of `-shared` to the linker. (ex. `gcc -o mylib.lib -static *.o -Wl,--subsystem,windows`).